# Como puedo imprimir los numeros impares y pares de un array (Por separado) PHP

Tags: php, php7, php5, backend, php8

```php
     <?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $valor = $_POST['valor'];
    $valor2 = $_POST['valor2'];
    $rep1 = [];
    $rep2 = [];


    echo "<h3> Array 1 </h3>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($valor); $i++) {

        echo "Valor: $valor[$i]<br>";
    }
    /*__________________________ARRAY 2 ________________________ */

    echo "<h3> Array 2 </h3> ";
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($valor2); $j++) {

        echo "Valor: $valor2[$j]<br>";
    }
    /*__________________________NUMEROS IMPAR - ARRAY 1 ________________________ */


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($valor); $i++) {
        if (($valor) % 2 != 0) {
            $rep1 = $valor[$i];
        }
    }
    echo "Valor: $rep1";
} //isset
```

parte del enunciado que quiero hacer es:

Carguen 2 vectores de 7 posiciones desde un formulario. Al presionar el botón de
“ENVIAR”, llamen a un archivo de PHP que haga lo siguiente:
a. Pase los datos de los formularios a los dos vectores
b. Cree un 3er vector que se llene alternando los datos de los 2 vectores anteriores
así:
 Los valores impares del vector 1 y,
 Los valores pares del vector 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido bien el enunciado:

*Cree un 3er vector que se llene alternando los datos de los 2 vectores anteriores así: Los valores impares del vector 1 y, Los valores pares del vector 2*.

Simplemente tienes que recorrer ambos vectores y metiendo en el tercer vector aquellos que sean impares del primer vector y aquellos que sean pares del segundo vector.

Dado que no tengo contexto de formulario, simularé un `$_POST` en el código para la prueba:

```
#Esto es un $_POST simulado para fines de prueba        
$_POST=array(
              'valor'=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
              'valor2'=>array(8,9,10,11,12,13,0)
            );

$valor = $_POST['valor'];
$valor2 = $_POST['valor2'];
$third=array();

foreach ($valor as $n) {
    if ($n % 2 === 0) {
        $third[]=$n;
    }
}

foreach ($valor2 as $n) {
    if ($n % 2 !== 0) {
        $third[]=$n;
    }
}

var_dump($third);
```

Salida:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  int(6)
  [3]=>
  int(9)
  [4]=>
  int(11)
  [5]=>
  int(13)
}
```

Hay como resultado en array de 6 elementos, en primer lugar, los valores impares del primer vector y en segundo lugar, los valores pares del segundo.